# Connection String : Already added name

Tags: .net, vb.net, app-config

Have seen same questions, but its all on ASP.Net, though I tried, `<clear />`, well it doesn't work since when I compile, it reverts my edits in the .config file.
I don't want to recreate my app, so a little help is greatly appreciated.
[image]

Tried to open it on notepad, to "edit" it, but as I've said, it does not apply.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NeoPiggery.My.MySettings.pigletsNewConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\piglets.accdb"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    <add name="NeoPiggery.My.MySettings.pigletsNewConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\pigletsNew.accdb"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Tried to add `<clear />` after the first connection string.. It worked. But the next time I Debug, same problem (Picture 1). Why does it keeps omitting my changes?? :/

Comment: You can open the config file in VS and save the changes.

Comment: It can be edited, but changes will be omitted if I debugged.

Comment: That does not make sense.

Comment: Yeah, me too. I don't know why, maybe because its an auto-generated code, nonetheless, external edit could have changed the outcome, but still. The same, after I debugged, I got the first picture error, and when I turn to the `.config` file, what I added disappeared.

Comment: Yes, but it should be auto generated one time - when you first add the datasource.

Comment: Why can't it save my changes? Check updated question.

Comment: Clean and Rebuild solution. Close solution and reopen it. Sometimes weird bug like this are fixed by these steps. Good luck!

Comment: you may want that as answer :)

Comment: That worked for you then?

Comment: yah, cleaned>rebuild>reopened.. Seems fine to me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean and Rebuild solution. Close solution and reopen it. Sometimes weird bug like this are fixed by these steps.